# How do you define a Cassandra CollectionMap nested in a UDT with duoshuo's PHP client library?

Tags: php, collections, cassandra

I have a `CollectionSet<UDT>` where UDT contains a `CollectionMap<int,boolean>`. I have not been able to find any documentation or example of how to define this when creating a new Cassandra\Type\CollectionSet for inserting into the table. There is a great example with a `CollectionList` ([found here](https://github.com/duoshuo/php-cassandra)) which is like this:

```
// CollectionSet<UDT>, where UDT contains: Int, Text, Boolean, 
// CollectionList<Text>, CollectionList<UDT>

new Cassandra\Type\CollectionSet([
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'string',
        'active' => true,
        'friends' => ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
        'drinks' => [['qty' => 5, 'brand' => 'Pepsi'], ['qty' => 3, 'brand' => 'Coke']]
    ],[
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'string',
        'active' => false,
        'friends' => ['string4', 'string5', 'string6'],
        'drinks' => []
    ]
], [
    [
    'type' => Cassandra\Type\Base::UDT,
    'definition' => [
        'id' => Cassandra\Type\Base::INT,
        'name' => Cassandra\Type\Base::VARCHAR,
        'active' => Cassandra\Type\Base::BOOLEAN,
        'friends' => [
            'type' => Cassandra\Type\Base::COLLECTION_LIST,
            'value' => Cassandra\Type\Base::VARCHAR
        ],
        'drinks' => [
            'type' => Cassandra\Type\Base::COLLECTION_LIST,
            'value' => [
                'type' => Cassandra\Type\Base::UDT,
                'typeMap' => [
                    'qty' => Cassandra\Type\Base::INT,
                    'brand' => Cassandra\Type\Base::VARCHAR
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]);
```

I've tried using the above example with several variations to accommodate the CollectionMap but nothing is working. My last attempt was this

```
new Cassandra\Type\CollectionSet($udt_array, [[
                'type'=>Cassandra\Type\Base::UDT,
                'definition' => [
                    'map_name' => [
                        'type' => Cassandra\Type\Base::COLLECTION_MAP,
                        'value' => [
                            Cassandra\Type\Base::INT,
                            Cassandra\Type\Base::BOOLEAN
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]])
```

which gives the error `Caught exception: Since v0.7, collection types should have \"definition\" directive.` I've also tried using 'definition' instead of 'value'. I'm running out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "definition" instead of "value". I tried this before but apparently I was doing something else wrong because this worked.

```
new Cassandra\Type\CollectionSet($udt_array, [[
                'type'=>Cassandra\Type\Base::UDT,
                'definition' => [
                    'map_name' => [
                        'type' => Cassandra\Type\Base::COLLECTION_MAP,
                        'definition' => [
                            Cassandra\Type\Base::INT,
                            Cassandra\Type\Base::BOOLEAN
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]])
```